# "Aborting transactions for path" when saving object to Firebase on Android

Tags: android, transactions, firebase, runtime-error

I'm having issues with some code which was working fine until today. Basically, i'm doing the standard create user object after auth for extra data.

But, when i was just testing the code below it no longer enters the onComplete method. Instead, i get the error in the log below about the transaction being aborted.

A Google brings up nothing, what could it be?

Code:

```
final Firebase userLocation = new Firebase(Constants.USERS_URL).child(uid);

    User newUser = new User(name, email);

    userLocation.setValue(newUser, new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
            if(firebaseError == null) {
                ...
            }
            else {
                ...
            }
        }
    });
```

Logs:

```
04-05 16:13:04.274 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/AuthenticationManager: Sending request to https://auth.firebase.com/v2/best-before/users with 2 query params
04-05 16:13:05.437 4855-4855/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore I/RegisterPresenter: Successfully created user account with uid: 4a97cb4b-4034-4f46-98c3-4104d1d649b7
04-05 16:13:05.437 4855-4855/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/RegisterPresenter: Creating user object
04-05 16:13:05.484 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/WebSocket: ws_1 - Reset keepAlive. Remaining: 0
04-05 16:13:05.502 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/RepoOperation: set: /users/4a97cb4b-4034-4f46-98c3-4104d1d649b7
04-05 16:13:05.503 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/DataOperation: set: /users/4a97cb4b-4034-4f46-98c3-4104d1d649b7 {
                                                                                email=xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com
                                                                                name=xxxxx xxxxxxxx
                                                                                timestampJoined={
                                                                                  timestamp={.sv=timestamp}
                                                                                }
                                                                              }
04-05 16:13:05.503 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/Persistence: Starting transaction.
04-05 16:13:05.524 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/Persistence: Persisted user overwrite in 20ms
04-05 16:13:05.536 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/Persistence: Transaction completed. Elapsed: 33ms
04-05 16:13:05.538 4855-4912/com.nicedistractions.bestbefore D/RepoOperation: Aborting transactions for path: /users/4a97cb4b-4034-4f46-98c3-4104d1d649b7. Affected: /users/4a97cb4b-4034-4f46-98c3-4104d1d649b7
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you find solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to reproduce this on Lollipop when I am connected to wifi, disable the actual internet connectivity, and then re-enable internet connection (all with the device remaining connected to wifi network). After this, if I try to perform a setValue() write, about 18 minutes will pass before Firebase reconnects and the setValue() completes. I reached out to the Firebase team and was told this is expected behavior due to the Android OS basically neglecting to informing apps when the connection is restored.

<s>The only way to resolve in my experience is either disabling and re-enabling WiFi, or restarting the app (restarting the activity won't help).</s>

Firebase support got back to me and suggested calling `goOffline()` followed by `goOnline()` - I verified this immediately reconnects the Firebase database. What I do now is set a Handler with my own timeout for setValue(), since I can't seem to depend on DatabaseError being thrown with onComplete().